# Failed to start media recorder in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, mediarecorder

I am using this code to record video from the front camera and show a preview in surface view:

```
public class MatchActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
View myButton;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;
TextView prepareid;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
String pathOfVideo;
TextView textmode;
ImageView imagemode;
boolean isRunning = false;
String PIC;
int ID;
operations op = new operations();
final boolean camerastate = op.checkcamera(getBaseContext());
private TextView mTimer;
private Camera mCamera;
private Button.OnClickListener BackToMainL = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        op.suoundeffect(v, getBaseContext());
        op.buttoneffect(v);
        new SweetAlertDialog(MatchActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("برای خروج مطمئن هستین ؟")
                .setConfirmText("بله")
                .setCancelText("نه ، ادامه بدیم")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        if (camerastate)
                            stopvideo();
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        Global.audioplay = true;
                        Global.flaginapp = false;
                        sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
};
private Button.OnClickListener CorrectAnswer = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        op.suoundeffect(v, getBaseContext());
        op.buttoneffect(v);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        if (camerastate)
            stopvideo();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MatchActivity.this, ResultPage.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        Global.flaginapp = true;
        b.putString("PATH", pathOfVideo);
        b.putString("PIC", PIC);
        b.putInt("Answer", 1);
        b.putInt("ID", ID);
        b.putString("Word", textmode.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        Global.audioplay = true;
        Global.flaginapp = false;
        finish();
    }
};
private Button.OnClickListener StartVideo
        = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View arg0) {
        myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        prepareid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " ثانیه ");
                isRunning = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                isRunning = false;
                if (camerastate)
                    stopvideo();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MatchActivity.this, ResultPage.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("PIC", PIC);
                b.putString("PATH", pathOfVideo);
                b.putString("Word", textmode.getText().toString());
                b.putInt("Answer", 0);
                b.putInt("ID", ID);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                Global.audioplay = true;
                Global.flaginapp = false;
                finish();
            }
        };
        startvideo();
    }
};

public static Camera openFrontalCamera() {
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT == cameraInfo.facing) {
            return Camera.open(i);
        }
    }
    return Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        new SweetAlertDialog(MatchActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("برای خروج مطمئن هستین ؟")
                .setConfirmText("بله")
                .setCancelText("نه ، ادامه بدیم")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        if (isRunning) {
                            if (camerastate) {
                                stopvideo();
                            }
                            countDownTimer.cancel();
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match);

    SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    op.Localize();
    recording = false;
    mCamera = openFrontalCamera();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    pathOfVideo = initMediaRecorder();
    surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    if (mCamera != null) {
        //continue flow
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MatchActivity.this, "Camera Not Availble", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    myButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.Prepare);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(StartVideo);

    ImageView BacktoMain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cancelgame);
    BacktoMain.setOnClickListener(BackToMainL);

    ImageView CorecctAnswer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correctanswer);
    CorecctAnswer.setOnClickListener(CorrectAnswer);

    textmode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmode);
    imagemode = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturemode);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    PIC = intent.getStringExtra("PIC");
    ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
    if (PIC.equals("TRUE")) {
        textmode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imagemode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    final String[] result = new String[1];
    API api = RestAdapter.createAPI();
    Call<CallBackWord> callbackCall = api.GetWord(ID, PIC);
    callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallBackWord>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CallBackWord> call, Response<CallBackWord> response) {
            CallBackWord resp = response.body();
            result[0] = resp.name;
            if (PIC.equals("TRUE")) {
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(result[0]).into(imagemode);
            } else {
                textmode.setText(result[0]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CallBackWord> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MatchActivity.this, "لطفا از اتصال اینترنت خود مطمئن شوید." + t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MatchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            Global.flaginapp = true;
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    prepareid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prepareid);
    mTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MatchActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 50);
    }

}

public void stopvideo() {
    recording = false;
    try {

        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();

        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to stop recorder", e);
    }
    mediaRecorder.release();
    mediaRecorder = null;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

public void startvideo() {
    mCamera.unlock();
    countDownTimer.start();
    mediaRecorder.start();
    recording = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

}

private String initMediaRecorder() {

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);  //get your own profile
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "hadskalme" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(90000); // Set max duration 90 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(15000000); // Set max file size 15M

    return String.valueOf(file.getAbsolutePath());
}

private void prepareMediaRecorder() {

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "  to prepare recorder", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!Global.flaginapp) {
        stopAudio();
        Global.audioplay = false;
    } else {
        Global.flaginapp = false;
        Global.audioplay = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Shared.init(getBaseContext());
    String background = Shared.read("backgroundmusic", null);
    if (Objects.equals(background, "okay") && !Global.audioplay) {
        Global.audioplay = true;
        playAudio();
    }
}

public void playAudio() {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
    startService(objIntent);
}

public void stopAudio() {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
    stopService(objIntent);
}
}
```

**but on some device (+500 device) below crash's report to me :**

```
lang.java.IllegalStateException
at media.android.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
at media.android.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:944)
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.startvideo(MatchActivity.java:286)
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity$3.onClick(MatchActivity.java:140)
at view.android.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
at view.android.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
at os.android.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**and this error: **

```
lang.java.NullPointerException
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.stopvideo(MatchActivity.java:274)
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity$4.onClick(MatchActivity.java:168)
at SweetAlert.pedant.cn.SweetAlertDialog.onClick(SweetAlertDialog.java:372)
at view.android.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
at view.android.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
at os.android.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at system.dalvik.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this error more than 1000 devices :

```
UnknownException
at hardware.android.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
at hardware.android.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:469)
at hardware.android.Camera.open(Camera.java:424)
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.openFrontalCamera(MatchActivity.java:149)
at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.onCreate(MatchActivity.java:194)
at app.android.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
at app.android.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at app.android.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
at app.android.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at app.android.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at app.android.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at system.dalvik.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
lang.java.RuntimeException: (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.hiup.hadskalme/ir.hiup.hadskalme.MatchActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service)
at app.android.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
at app.android.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at app.android.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at app.android.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at system.dalvik.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i solve this problem ?
(this error appears on different devices and different android versions) 
Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate the line where each of those exceptions occur.

Comment: the error line's written in above text, but now i re-write error lines : at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.startvideo(MatchActivity.java:286) , at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.stopvideo(MatchActivity.java:274) , at hadskalme.hiup.ir.MatchActivity.openFrontalCamera(MatchActivity.java:149)